# Rocket.chat - login via Rest API - 401

Tags: xmlhttprequest, rocket.chat

I'm trying to login to my Rocket.chat app on localhost via API.
When I'm sending POST to http://localhost:3000/api/login with data:     `{"user":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}`
I'm getting response 401 with status error, no matter if used xhr request, axios or jquery ajax.
BUT when I send the same data with python virtualenv or curl, the response is 200 and status success.
What am I doing wrong? Why POST fails when sending with javascript and passes when sending with python or curl?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000/api/login/', true);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword"
}));
// result: {status: "error", message: "Unauthorized"}
```

I'm sending login request with no header, because:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

returns 500

Here are request details from Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running rocket chat on a domain which is different from the domain from which you are making ajax request. The domain and port from which you make ajax request should be same as the domain and port of the destination url. This is because of a security feature in web browsers called Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

To fix this error your web server needs to allow requests from other domains.

Comment: even if I post it from the same domain, result is 401 - [link](http://postimg.org/image/nr29ddcm5/).

Comment: There was another issue in my code, but Your answer is 100% right, Thanks! Now I need only to make my Rocket.chat server allow requests from other domains in a language that I do not know at all :)

Answer (score -1):

try this Code

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/api/login/");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF- 8");xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({name:"myusername", time:"mypassword"}));
```

Comment: With your code I get response: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/login/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500